# Angular View not updating after model changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a simple angular application to play audio using JavaScript web  Audio Object below is

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'media player';
  audio;
  currentTime: number;

  constructor() {
    this.audio = new Audio();
    this.audio.src = './Music/demo2.MP3';
    this.audio.play();
    this.currentTime = this.audio.currentTime;
  }
}
```

and
app.component.ts

```
<h4>{{ currentTime }}</h4>
```

everything works fine but the view isn't update as the model changes

Comment: Can you not bind to `audio.currentTime` instead?

Comment: This is because this line `this.currentTime = this.audio.currentTime;` only runs once when the component is loaded. You need to make sure that line updates every second. Or @user184994 approach could also work.

Comment: @PraveenM yes i undersand `this.currentTime = this.audio.currentTime;` only run once. please do you know a way to make these work.

Comment: @OchuiPrincewill You can use JavaScript `setInterval` function to update the value every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular does update binding on browser events for the same Angular uses `zonejs` which monkey patches several browser events, and it fires `detectChanges` method to keep binding in a sync.

In this case Angular doesn't update binding, since `Audio` API event's doesn't monkey patch by zonejs. For such scenarios you have to run change detection manually to update bindings manually. You could use `ontimeupdate` event handler of `audio` API.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'media player';
  audio;
  currentTime: number;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
  }
  ngOnInit(){
     this.audio = new Audio();
     this.audio.src = './Music/demo2.MP3';
     this.audio.play();
     //this will make sure to update when time updates.
     this.audio.ontimeupdate = (event) => {
        this.currentTime = this.audio.currentTime;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Here is the `setInterval` approach

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'media player';
  audio: Audio;
  currentTime: number;

  constructor() {
    this.audio = new Audio();
    this.audio.src = './Music/demo2.MP3';
    this.audio.play();
    this.currentTime = this.audio.currentTime;
  }
  
   ngOnInit() {
     setInterval(() => {
      this.currentTime = this.audio.currentTime;
    }, 1000);
   }
}
```

But as the **@user184994** mentioned, simply just by using the `audio.currentTime` on the frontend might be far simpler and effective approach.

```html
<h4>{{ audio.currentTime }}</h4>
```

Comment: I consider `setInterval` a code smell. It complicates the code and tests, and doesn't seem necessary given when the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @stealththeninja OP's problem is that `currentTime` not updating constantly when the audio is playing, this is an approach that I would consider. That's why I mentioned of using the `audio.currentTime` itself, as I'm assuming, will get updated as the audio is playing, is far stable and effective.

Comment: It's preferable to use event listeners over `setInterval`, and media elements have a `timeupdate` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate

Comment: @stealththeninja yes, I used the same in my answer :)