# How to move a radial audio progress bar by clicking anywhere on the track?

Tags: javascript, html, math, html5-audio, calculation

I have this circular DIV tag with `height` and `width` of `160px` (the green div). I calculated the radius which is `80px`  and its circumference which is `877.93px`. That white line outside of red div which is going around the red circular div you see is audio progress bar.

Now I want to make this circular, green `Div` which is behind the red `Div` tag clickable so that if user clicks on any point in front of the progress bar on this gradient `Div` tag, it moves the progress bar to that point by changing audio.currentTime.

So far, I have this code but what I get is not accurate at all and it also relies on the center of the green circular `Div`. So if user clicks anywhere closer to center, the calculation won't be so accurate.

That white progress bar is a `Div` itself and made by DaisyUI. White progress bar moves based on the audio.currentTime and if audio time updates it moves forward and backward accordingly.

Can anyone here help me with this problem please?

If there is any information missing in this thread please let me know.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Tab1Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.audioProgress = 0;
  $scope.startX = 0;
  $scope.startValue = 0;
  $scope.progressbar = document.getElementById('progressBar');

  $scope.play = function() {
    const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      $scope.playIcon = 'pause';
      audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
        if (audio.duration <= 60) {
          $scope.audioProgress = Math.floor((audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 100));
        } else {
          $scope.audioProgress = Math.floor((audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 100));
        }
      });
      return;
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      $scope.playIcon = 'play';
    }
  };

  $scope.onMouseDown = function(event) {
    $scope.startDrag(event.clientX);
  };

  $scope.onTouchStart = function(event) {
    $scope.startDrag(event.touches[0].clientX);
  };

  $scope.startDrag = function(startX) {
    // Get the initial mouse position and progress value
    $scope.startX = startX;
    $scope.startValue = parseInt($scope.audioProgress, 10);

    // Register drag events
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', $scope.drag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', $scope.dragEnd);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', $scope.drag, {
      passive: false
    });
    document.addEventListener('touchend', $scope.dragEnd, {
      passive: false
    });
  };

  $scope.drag = function(event) {
    const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    const circle = document.getElementById('progressBar');
    const rect = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
    const clientY = (event instanceof MouseEvent ? event.clientY : event.touches[0].clientY);
    const clientX = (event instanceof MouseEvent ? event.clientX : event.touches[0].clientX);
    const delta = (clientX) - $scope.startX;
    let newValue = $scope.startValue + (delta / 10);
    newValue = Math.min(Math.max(newValue, 0), 100);
    const dx = clientX - (rect.left + rect.width / 2);
    const dy = clientY - (rect.top + rect.height / 2);
    const angleInRadians = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    let angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * (180 / Math.PI + 90);
    if (angleInDegrees < 0) {
      angleInDegrees = 877.93 + angleInDegrees;
    }
    audio.currentTime = (angleInDegrees / 360) * audio.duration;
  };

  $scope.dragEnd = function() {
    // Unregister drag events
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', $scope.drag);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', $scope.dragEnd);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', $scope.drag);
    document.removeEventListener('touchend', $scope.dragEnd);
  };

});
```

```css
.bg-red {
  background-color: #dc2626;
}

.w-md {
  width: 135px;
}

.h-md {
  height: 135px;
}

.rounded-full {
  border-radius: 9999px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.rounded-half {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@2.51.6/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Tab1Controller" style="width: 160px;height: 160px;" class="bg-green-600 relative rounded-half z-9899989 flex justify-center items-center">
  <div ng-mousedown="onMouseDown($event)" ng-touchstart="onTouchStart($event)" draggable="true" class="radial-progress rounded-full text-accent mx-auto shadow-round-spread" ng-init="progressbar = {}" id="progressBar" style="--value: {{audioProgress}}; --size: 10rem; --thickness: 0.7rem">
    <!--  -->
  </div>
  <div ng-click="play()" class="bg-red" style="width: 135px; height: 135px; border-radius: 50%; position: absolute; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <!-- icon Play -->
    <i ng-class="{'ion-pause -translate-x-2': playIcon === 'pause', 'ion-play -translate-x-1': playIcon !== 'pause'}" class="text-6xl ion-play text-accent pl-4 rounded-full bg-red"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<audio src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/download/audio/2023/04/27/audio_d6ce814591.mp3?filename=reflected-light-147979.mp3" controls id="audio" class="hidden invisible opacity-0"></audio>
```

[image]

Comment: As a plain HTML and JS question, I can strongly recommend turning this into a runnable snippet.

Comment: show all  your code (html css  js )

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 
Sorry the code was angular but now I edited my question and it is runnable. I just want to make that progress bar you see it as a weird bluish color, draggable by click on the progress bar container or touch event.

Comment: @paliz
Thanks for giving this suggestion. i edited my question and all available styles and html codes are all there.

Comment: Remember to run it though =D (you're trying to load a modules as "not a  module" right now, so there's a big console error that obscures the snippet itself)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Oops sorry! Thanks for pointing that out, that was an issue with ionic js library which I removed it

Comment: Just looking at what your code does, it does not appear to update the progress bar while it's playing, is that intentional for the purpose of the example? Also, just so folks understand, is the question purely about what  should happen when the progress bar is click-dragged or touch-dragged? Because you might be running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866433/740553) at the moment.